# My Node.js website on vercel displaying normally in Incognito, but not otherwise

Tags: next.js, deployment, hosting, vercel

So i hosted this node, express website on vercel. Its a static website with no database. The problem I see quite often is related to local cache and i have little to no idea how to solve it. When i update something in the website and then push it to github, my website updates, however if I have already visited that website from my device, there is a great chance something messes up, for e.g a button may not be working. However if i visit the website on the same device using incognito everything works like a charm.

I have no idea about edge or serverless functions and everything is on default. I did try to purge data cache but that did no good. Should i just wait it out for devices to delete their cache on their own or is there something i can do?

I can share any code/detail thats needed.